# PyLint: E1101:Class X has no 'Y' member', even though defined in __init__

Tags: python, pylint

I have following code:

```
class Class1(object):
    """Demo Class"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.lines = []

    @classmethod
    def from_log(cls, log):
        """Instantiate from log"""

        cls = Class1()
        cls.name = 'log'

        for line in log.splitlines():
            cls.lines.append(line)  # <-- pylint message here

        return cls


OBJ = Class1.from_log("line1\nline2")
print(OBJ.lines)
```

Which causes pylint to complain:

```
E1101:Class 'Class1' has no 'lines' member
```

What's wrong here? And since it complains about `cls.lines`, why doesn't it complain about `cls.name`?

I am using:

- pylint 1.7.4
- Python 3.6.2

**EDIT:** Thanks to user2357112 I realized that I misunderstood the type of cls. cls is the class-object of Class1. What I am creating is an instance of Class1. That's different. Reusing it confuses pylint. The correct code looks like that:

```
class Class1(object):
    """Demo Class"""

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.lines = []

    @classmethod
    def from_log(cls, log):
        """Instanciate from log-file"""

        newobj = Class1() # <-- don't reuse cls. create a new variable.
        newobj.name = 'log'

        for line in log.splitlines():
            newobj.lines.append(line)

        return newobj
```

It can even be:

```
newobj = cls()
```

Comment: You've reused the `cls` variable. Don't do that.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I misunderstood what cls is. Replacing cls = Class1() with newobj = Class1() works now. Or even new newobj = cls().

Comment: user2357112, I added the correct example. If you add this as an answer, I'll choose it as accepted answer.